# Merge neighboring regions in R (aggregate spatial data)?

Tags: r, geospatial

I guess I needed to rephrase my awfully worded previous question (deleted it). Here's another try. I want to join to adjacent regions, in a way that their common border disappears and only their outer line can be seen.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
require(shapefiles)
require(sp)

xx <- readShapeSpatial(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1],
                   IDvar="FIPSNO", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66"))

# show all the subregions
plot(xx)
```

[image]

Now let's consider only regions regions 3 and 5

```
plot(xx[c(3,5),])
```

How can I just aggregate these regions. In practice what I want to do is like having a map of the whole continent showing all countries and producing a map that shows North America and South America.

To me this looks like a pretty common task but I can't find the right function to do it so far. Do I just miss a function or can I simply to it manually?

[image]

Comment: Use `unionSpatialPolygons()` from the `maptools` package: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21360/merging-2-polygon-adjacent-to-each-other-using-r

Comment: I know your question says in R, but the spatial manipulation library par excellence is postgres/postgis. You can also write R stored procedures in postgres, see http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgresql_plr_tut01, which means you get the benefits of spatial indexing and functions from postgis and the stats of R. There is a shp to postgres import function as well that ships with postgres.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `rgeos` package provides a number of excellent tools for handling `Spatial*` data, that can be used in this case.

For example:

```
library(rgeos)
regionOfInterest <- gUnion(xx[3,], xx[5,])
```

This also has the same result, and may be more useful for multiple polygons:

```
regionOfInterest <- gUnionCascaded(xx[c(3,5), ])
```

The result from `plot(regionOfInterest)`:

[image]